# I saw a video of a trick of someone untangling a wire that seems to contradict what I learned in topology

Tags: general-topology

Is the wire in the figure below homotopic to a wire between the two points that just go straight above the pipe? My knowledge of topology is very basic, and it seems to me that the pipe can be seen as some kind of hole, so the wire seems to really be impossible to untie. However, there is a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Up2_NyAzWQ4) that seems to untie it. Is it a trick or is my intuition wrong, and if so is it easy and evident to tell why they are homotopic without having to watch the video? Or something else that I am misunderstanding?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTd7U.jpg)

Comment: You can untie any knot by unthreading one of the loose ends of the rope (wire). In the video, instead of unthreading the end with the plug on it (because it won't fit under the stick), parts of the knot are extended under the stick towards the loose end, and the unthreading happens there, with the same effect. Note that the unthreading changes the topology of the knot.

Comment: @DominikS Thanks, I got it now, I was thinking about it all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a geometric obstruction here, not a topological obstruction.

If the head of the wire was the same size as the rest of the wire, you would easily straighten it out. A priori you would need to bring the head of the wire under the bar, so you can pass it through the loop to straighten it out. However, one can instead move the loop to the other side, so that passing the head under the geometric obstruction is unnecessary.